# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid error while invoking Firefox through Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to invoke a firefox browser using Selenium webdriver from below python code..

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Initializing the WebDriver for Firefox browser
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\selenium\\mozilla\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

# Closing the reference
driver.quit()
```

but it is always throwing an error like below, however this is working for Chrome browser.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Practice/FirefoxSample.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\selenium\\mozilla\\geckodriver.exe")
  File "C:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 139, in __init__
    firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile(firefox_profile)
  File "C:\Python\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py", line 78, in __init__
    ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns("parent.lock", "lock", ".parentlock"))
  File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 309, in copytree
    names = os.listdir(src)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\selenium\\mozilla\\geckodriver.exe'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I missing here?

I have also tried upgrading the selenium package using the pip

```
pip install -U selenium
```

**Additional info:** running the Firefox latest version (59.0.2), Python (3.6.5) and Selenium Gecko webdriver (0.20.0). Not sure if anything is needed to help on this.

Comment: I have also tried upgrading the selenium package using the pip

Comment: I have also tried upgrading the selenium package using the pip

`pip install -U selenium`

Also, running the Firefox latest version (59.0.2), Python (3.6.5) and Selenium Gecko webdriver (0.20.0). Not sure if anything is needed to help on this.

Comment: maybe use https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager instead of installing each driver manually?

Answer (score 33):

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows :

- You need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* through single backslash i.e. `\` along with the raw i.e. `r` switch as follows :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\selenium\mozilla\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  driver.quit()
  ```
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Comment: I found this while testing randomly loading chrome/edge/firefox drivers, turns out chrome & edge do not need executable_path explicitly assigned while firefox does. Leaving this comment so others can avoid having to rediscover that trap.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is looking for the directory, not the executable.
You have to point to the directory where geckodriver.exe is placed. Do not include geckodriver.exe in the string argument.

Instead of

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\selenium\\mozilla\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Do

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\selenium\\mozilla")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this Q&A while testing code to randomly load chrome/edge/firefox drivers.

Turns out chrome & edge do not need executable_path explicitly assigned while firefox does.

I'd also reccomend randomly setting the window size before opening a session to aid in meachanisms to defeat scraping. (be aware that may affect screen layout so be conservative in range of sizes).

[How to set window size in Selenium Chrome Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012755/how-to-set-window-size-in-selenium-chrome-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work without any errors or warnings

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# provide a full path of the driver
path = r"F:\scraping\selenium\geckodriver.exe"

# pass the driver path as a service
service = Service(path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps. Then you will be able to invoke the firefox browser.

[image: Open cmd and enter "where python"]

[image: Inside Scripts folder paste the latest geckodriver]

[image: import "from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary"]