# Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver

```
from selenium import webdriver;
browser= webdriver.Firefox();
browser.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org');
```

When I try to run this code, it gives me an `error message`:

```
Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.
```

Any thoughts-highly appreciated!

Comment: You need put the webdriver for firefox in you script director or system path. link: <https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/>

Comment: Please find the below link to get the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75257015/14526303

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This error message...

```
Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line.
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) was unable to find the *Firefox* binary at the default location. Additionally you haven't passed the `moz:firefoxOptions.binary` capability.

---

### Solution

Possibly within your system [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) is installed in a custom location and these cases you need to pass the *absolute path* of the *Firefox* binary through the `moz:firefoxOptions.binary` capability as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\geckodriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion in:

- [SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908154/sessionnotcreatedexception-message-expected-browser-binary-location-but-unabl/64908883#64908883)
- [InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable error using GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64034859/invalidargumentexception-message-binary-is-not-a-firefox-executable-error-usin/64035303#64035303)
- [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000401/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location/66000618#66000618)

Comment: I had to restart RIDE for it to see this change after installing firefox

Answer (score 26):

Firefox was not installed on my system at all. That's why this error came up.

Answer (score 9):

same issue here:

- Environment

  - OS: `Mac`

    - Not install `Firefox` application
    - has installed `geckodriver`, can found in `PATH`
- Error Reason: Not installed `Firefox`
- Solution: (goto [firefox official site](https://www.mozilla.org/zh-CN/firefox/mac/) to download and) install Firefox

Answer (score 3):

I have uninstalled firefox and installed it again which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Before this ensure that path variable has include for geckodriver [click here to download driver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and run below python script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download appropriate web driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and put it into folder where your py file is. Also you can put it anywhere as long as the location of the file it is in your system path.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium uses a **web driver** (a specific one for each web browser) in order to communicate with the **browser installed on your system** (Firefox in your case).

To use Firefox, you have to:

1. Download its web driver from
   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
2. Put the web driver in a **specific location** in the file system (same folder as the python script for example)
3. Add the web driver location path when **initializing** in the python code.

So the final code would look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox('./geckodriver')

browser.get('https://www.python.org/')
```

Note: Sometimes a **newer version** of the web driver isn't compatible with an **older version of the browser installed on your system**.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem (Windows, Firefox v99, Selenium 4.1.4, geckodriver 0.31.0), the path to exe file and the driver initialisation were set correctly, solved the issue by changing the win32 by win64 version of geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

as a side note for selenium/firefox (but with C#, not Python), this issue is quite relevant now in the sense that firefox location looks to be stored in windows in a new regedit location. Indeed geckodriver is looking in regedit location documented here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE WOW6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\[VERSION]\Main\PathToExe


HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\[VERSION]\Main\PathToExe
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities/firefoxOptions

when on my machine it is there:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 109.0\bin
```

With the version number stored here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\mozilla.org\Mozilla
```

and I set the selenium driver with C# Api with (*path hardcoded for the poc*):

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
...
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

check whether firefox is installed in your system

```
firefox -v
```

if not, install using snap

```
sudo snap install firefox
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to download geckodriver.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```py
from selenium import webdriver;

browser= webdriver.Firefox('./geckodriver');
browser.get('http://www.seleniumhq.org');
```