# Instapy issue, probbably connected to firefox webdriver

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver, instapy

So this is my code:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="<my_username>", password="<my_password>")
session.login()
session.like_by_tags(["bmw", "mercedes"], amount=5)
```

And it returns an error message:

```
InstaPy Version: 0.6.13
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "C:/Users/budim/InstaPy"

  0%|          | 0/1407 [00:00<?, ?kb/s]
 28%|██▊       | 387/1407 [00:00<00:00, 3774.35kb/s]
 54%|█████▍    | 765/1407 [00:00<00:00, 3257.82kb/s]
 78%|███████▊  | 1095/1407 [00:00<00:00, 2863.47kb/s]
 99%|█████████▊| 1387/1407 [00:00<00:00, 2687.05kb/s]
1408kb [00:00, 2887.22kb/s]                          
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\budim\Desktop\natjecanje iz inf\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = InstaPy(username="<my_username>", password="<my_password>")
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 123, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\budim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line

[Finished in 6.2s]
```

I do not understand why this is happening. If someone can offer some help, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Is firefox installed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with instapy, it is related to firefox

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

the GeckoDriver (firefox web driver) was unable to find the Firefox binary at the default location.

[expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location)