# Expected browser binary location

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having issue with Firefox in selenium

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service


service_obj = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service_obj)
```

Then I receive this error

```
Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line
```

Any help would be appreciated

I'm trying to invoke Firefox browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a similar question with an approved answer below:

[Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided using GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location)

You can try to check if it solves your problem.